# Cocoa Touch - Moving a image using accelerometer

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I change this code to add a UIImage and then move it using the accelerometer? Then how do you detect if it collides with another image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to include some code?  There's none shown.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer may be helpful.

Comment: I have never used the accelerometer so I have no code to start.